# Enforcing calling a method in all base classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

How can one implement a method which calls another method recursively for all base classes? Conceptually:

```
class C {
public:
    magical void recursiveWork() {
         thisClass::doWork();
         if (baseClassExists) {
              baseClass::recursiveWork();
         }
    }

    void doWork() {
        printf("bar");
    }
}

class D : public C {
public:
    void doWork() {
         printf("foo");
    }
}

D d;
d.recursiveWork(); // prints "foobar"
```

Comment: You could have a convention where each class that has a base class, e.g. class D, has a private "typedef C Base" and then have a convention where base class method is always called via Base:: e.g. "Base::recursiveWork()". Microsoft Visual C++ has a nonstandard keyword __super for this purpose.

Comment: And for the "if(baseClassExists)" part you might find typeid useful: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Comment: @V-R 1) Thanks for the tip about __super. Any idea if something similar exists in clang?

Comment: 2) I don't see how typeid can be used for implementing if(baseClassExists)

Comment: __super should be available in clang: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13236

Comment: Doesn't look like it's supported in the latest Xcode

Comment: Concerning `if(baseClassExists)` I just thought you might try something like `if(std::type_index(typeid(D))!=std::type_index(typeid(D::Base))) Base::recursiveWork();` and possibly make the baseless class C still `typedef C Base` to make sure the type name `Base` is always available for the `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something to indicate the base class, like `base_type` below, and then recursively check if `DoIt` exists. (in this case I checked if `base_type` is different from self, in case of the most base class). Of course, it won't work with multiple inheritance (it should have something to identify all `base_type`'s), and be careful with object slicing when going up on base classes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class A1
{
public:
   using base_type = A1;
   virtual ~A1(){}
   virtual void DoIt(){ std::cout << "A1\n"; }
};

class A : public A1
{
public:
   using base_type = A1;
   virtual void DoIt(){
       std::cout << "A\n"; 
   }
};

class B : public A
{    
public:
    using base_type = A;
    virtual void DoIt(){
        std::cout << "B\n"; 
    }
};

template<class...> using void_t = void;

template<class, class = void>
struct has_do_it : std::false_type { constexpr static bool value = false; };

template<class T>
struct has_do_it<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T&>().DoIt())>> : std::true_type { constexpr static bool value = true; };

template<typename T>
void DoItRec(T t)
{
    if (has_do_it<T>::value) {
        t.DoIt();
        if(!std::is_same<T, typename T::base_type>::value)
        {
            typename T::base_type& base = t; // get base part (object slicing)
            DoItRec(base); 
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    DoItRec(b);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a04622255f9b205)

Comment: Interesting! And this would be even nicer with something like __super which was mentioned by @V-R (and which I don't know of in clang, in Xcode at least)